# Get specific value with Spring JDBC multiple condition java

Tags: java, sql, spring

I try to get data with multiple conditions in Spring database with this code

```
public void AbsenStaff(int id, String category) {
    Staff staff = new Staff();
    String sql = "Select Absensi from Karyawan WHERE id=? AND Category=?";
    int a = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] { id },new Object[]{category},Integer.class);
    staff.setjmlhAbsensi(a);
}
```

However, IntelliJ gives me this error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'queryForObject(
     java.lang.String, 
     java.lang.Object[], 
     java.lang.Object[], 
     java.lang.Class<java.lang.Integer>)'
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send all parameter values in an object array, [so you are calling a different method.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-int:A-java.lang.Class-)

**Try like this:**

```java
public void AbsenStaff(int id, String category) {
    Staff staff = new Staff();
    String sql = "Select Absensi from Karyawan WHERE id=? AND Category=?";
    int a = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{id, category}, Integer.class);
    staff.setjmlhAbsensi(a);
}
```

**In addition,** this usage has been depracated in the current version. I suggest you write as below:

> jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Integer.class, id, category);

Answer (score 1):

According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html

These are the valid method signatures for the queryForObject method

1. queryForObject(String sql, Class requiredType)
2. queryForObject(String sql, Class requiredType, Object... args)
3. queryForObject(String sql, Object[] args, Class requiredType)
4. queryForObject(String sql, Object[] args, int[] argTypes, Class requiredType)
5. queryForObject(String sql, Object[] args, int[] argTypes, RowMapper rowMapper)
6. queryForObject(String sql, Object[] args, RowMapper rowMapper)
7. queryForObject(String sql, RowMapper rowMapper)
8. queryForObject(String sql, RowMapper rowMapper, Object... args)

So you must choose one of these (according to your needs) and provide the parameters in the right order and with the right data types.

I suppose you want to use this one

```
queryForObject(
  String sql, 
  Object[] args, 
  Class<T> requiredType)
```

In this case, you should use

```
int a = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
  sql, 
  new Object[] {id,category},
  Integer.class);
```